# Table for a not-quite-tabular data layout in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, layout, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following layout, which is essentially a details screen.

I'm using bootstrap and a table could handle it fairly easily but it's not as straight-forward as a regular list/tabular type table.

Would the better approach be to use divs for each row and labels and spans within for the labels and data?

[image]

Comment: I prefer to use a `dl` list for this situation, but styling is not as straightforward...

Comment: You are right that it's not tabular, though. Tuple sets are like a single column table at best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

**jsFiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/WMVke/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3 text-right">
          Title
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
          Apples and Oranges
        </div>
        <div class="span3 text-right">
          Date
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            11/09/2013
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6 text-right">
          Content
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
          <a href="#">Resp.P.91.pdf <span class="icon-file"></span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's quite a lot of markup... and notice I set the width to 940px because making this work responsively requires that you customize things a bit more and avoid clearing any of these floats until it gets too small.

So this can easily turn into something bigger, but do let us know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks, this is workable. However, in the end I used a table :)